# Why Angular 9 not caching the static files?

Tags: javascript, css, angular, caching, browser-cache

For some reason browser pulls fresh style.css and the main bundle from server every time the page is loaded:

[image]

I packaged\deployed my app using  `ng build --prod --output-hashing none`

Index file looks simple too:

```
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;400;500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <base href="/">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css"></head>
<body>
  <ep-layout>
    <div class="spinner-border text-light" style="width: 3rem; height: 3rem;" role="status">
      <span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>
    </div>
  </ep-layout>
<script src="runtime-es2015.js" type="module"></script>
<script src="runtime-es5.js" nomodule defer></script>
<script src="polyfills-es5.js" nomodule defer></script>
<script src="polyfills-es2015.js" type="module"></script>
<script src="scripts.js" defer></script>
<script src="main-es2015.js" type="module"></script>
<script src="main-es5.js" nomodule defer></script>
```

Is there something I am doing wrong? Also, I have realized my build process creates scripts.js which is very unusual.

Thanks much for the help.

Comment: apologies if is a stupid question, do you have selected no-caché in your browser?

Comment: @Eliseo I think my browser doesn't matter, it should cache in the user's browser. However, caching is not disabled on my browser.

Comment: @foo-baar I think Eliseo is refering to [this "Disable cache" checkbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/buaNj.png). If you have that one checked, it wont use caching. But that doesn't mean that it doesn't for your users. If you haven't checked it, what are the response headers of those scripts?

Comment: @Ivar Yup I got that part, However, you raised a really good point, this is ng running in asp.net mvc with cookie-based AUTH and hence response headers look like this:

Accept-Ranges: bytes
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store
Content-Length: 1090796
Content-Type: application/javascript
Date: Mon, 08 Jun 2020 14:43:56 GMT
ETag: "7933fdc313bd61:0"

Comment: @Ivar Looks like this is the reason.